# Neo4j: Sort a large resultset by total relationships?

Tags: graph, lucene, neo4j

Is it possible to take a large subset of nodes and sort them by total relationships? Or to put it another way, is it possible to return a large resultset from neo4j with the most connected nodes at the top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try

```
START node=node(*) 
MATCH node-[rel]-() 
RETURN id(node) as id, count(rel) as count 
ORDER BY count DESC
```

See this sample database: http://console.neo4j.org/r/c3tfc3

Comment: but it won't be fast yet as it is a graph global query which touches all your nodes and rels, and so has to be cached in memory to be quick. If you need that information more often consider storing the counts on the nodes or connecting the top-nodes to a well known reference node.